# Como adicionar a Class imagick (php)?

Tags: php, imagemagick

```
<?php

$images = new Imagick(glob('dog.JPG'));

foreach($images as $image) {


    $image->thumbnailImage(1024,0);

}

$images->writeImages();
```

Devolveu o seguinte erro

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tm/index.php.

Como faço para resolver?

Comment: Já leu a [documentação oficial](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php?ImageMagick=1dakqo4bbje35ce0voe8pjtqe1#macosx)?

Comment: em que diretoria coloco a versão . Nao da pra fazer download (The requested URL was not found on this server.)

Comment: o link para fazer o download não esta disponível alguem tem solução